# Can we have a blog for our salesforce community site

Tags: discussion

I just want to bring this up for discussion to see the interest among our users in having a community driven blog for our salesforce stackexchange site..

here's a getting started post I came across - [guidelines for getting started](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)

There are few communities within stackexchange which runs their blogs
 - [Stakexchange Blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs)

I m not saying we should have a blog just becos other sites hv one, but I have been thinking on what can we do in a blog that we can't do with meta / chat that can help our community..

something on the lines of

- Lot of the our contributors have their own individual blogs, podcasts, etc.. will it help our users if those posts gets mentioned / cross posted here
- highlight some of our community member's contribution - monthly / quarterly recognitions
- possibly host a mini hackathon / challenges related to salesforce
- sharing any interesting / fun / crazy / pain points & facts we face in our everyday life related to force platform that can't go in Q & A or meta

happy to hear more from others on this topic..

Answer (score 4):

For a variety of reasons, the [Community Blogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why) are no longer being created for sites. While Stack Exchange won't create these anytime soon, we've had other sites request it and the suggestion to them has been [to use something like Medium](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/552) as an outlet.  [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/we-have-a-blog) setup a blog on [Medium](https://medium.com/universe-factory) and you might be able to do the same.

If there is interest in starting a blog for Salesforce, then I'd suggest looking at that route.